# Export/import SPWeb to rootweb of new SPSite results in empty + missing groups

Tags: groups, export, import

We exported a SubSite using `Export-SPWeb` with **IncludeUserSecurity** and **versions**.
Subsequently we imported the export to the *root of a newly created SiteCollection* on the same WebApp (SharePoint 2016).

When we did this in our environment, all groups and users are intact, but on our client environment **all groups are empty** at the new SPSite/Web.

Besides that, when listing the groups via PowerShell, we notice that some groups are missing from the SPWeb, though they are part of the groups at the SPSite.
Meaning the groups were imported, but not added to the SPWeb for some reason.

Anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We didn't find a way to fix this issue so that Import-SPWeb would import the users, so we used custom PowerShell scripts to do some extra things as part of the promotion:

- Sync SiteCollection and SubSite features
- Sync Users/Groups

That seemed to be sufficient for us, but mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

Subwebs and root webs are very different in a few respects, and I'm not surprised that some things are broken. For example the root web will have a user info list while the subweb will not. There are other differences but that's probably what's getting you. In any case I would not recommend doing this, especially for publishing sites.

Comment: Thank you for the response. It was working great on our environments though, how would you recommend moving the SubSite to the rootweb of a new SiteCollection?